# Custom Page Template in WordPress returns 404 Error

Tags: wordpress

I'm making a WordPress theme of my own and I want to add a new page for 'Resources'. I'm using Custom Page Templates and I created a file named 'page-resources.php' in my theme's folder - wp-content/themes/mytheme/page-resources.php.
I added a comment on the top of the page to enable my custom page to show in the template dropdown of the  Page section.

```
/* Template Name: Resources Page */
```

I selected 'Resources Page' from the template dropdown on my ' Page' page. But when I view the page, it returns a 404 error.

The permalink to the page is http(://)localhost/mytheme/resources/

Comment: What are the parentheses for in the URL? Does http://localhost/mytheme return a correct page? Is the "resources" page set to be publicly visible? (It can be "Draft", "Pending review" or "Private" in default WP.)

Comment: @muka.gergely Apologies for the parentheses, I was using them to make the link stand out here. As for your questions, localhost/mytheme does return the homepage. The visibility of the page is set to public.

Comment: If you create another page with the same template, does it show up? (I think you should check the page before AND after assigning it a template - then it would be clear that the template is to blame or not).